# Oracle SQL how to club all email addresses under one ID

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have a simple, sample query in oracle sql
How do I club all the email addresses under one ID

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(E.ID),
    CASE WHEN G.EMAIL_CODE='EMAIL' THEN G.EMAIL_ADDRESS END AS EMAIL1,
    CASE WHEN G.EMAIL_CODE='ABCE' THEN G.EMAIL_ADDRESS END AS EMAIL2
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN GENERAL_EMAIL G ON (G.ID=E.ID)
GROUP BY 
    E.ID,
    G.EMAIL_CODE,
    G.EMAIL_ADDRESS
ORDER BY E.ID;
```

Comment: can you please tell, how do you want the output to look like?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **NOT** a function; it applies to all columns in the row.

Comment: and using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same sub-query is pointless as `GROUP BY` will return a single row per group so `DISTINCT` is not going to do anything additional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to aggregate the values into a single row then use `GROUP BY` and `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT E.ID,
       LISTAGG(G.EMAIL_ADDRESS, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
         AS emails
FROM   EMPLOYEE E
       INNER JOIN GENERAL_EMAIL G ON (G.ID=E.ID)
GROUP BY E.ID
ORDER BY E.ID;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE general_email (id, email_code, email_address) AS
SELECT 1, 'EMAIL', 'alice@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'EMAIL', 'abbot@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'ABCDE', 'alice_abbot@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'EMAIL', 'beryl@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'EMAIL', 'baron@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ABCDE', 'beryl_baron@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'EMAIL', 'carol@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'EMAIL', 'count@example.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | EMAILS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abbot@example.com,alice@example.com,alice_abbot@example.com |
| 2 | baron@example.com,beryl@example.com,beryl_baron@example.com |
| 3 | carol@example.com,count@example.com |

or, with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT E.ID,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE WHEN G.EMAIL_CODE='EMAIL' THEN G.EMAIL_ADDRESS END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.EMAIL_ADDRESS) AS email1,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE WHEN G.EMAIL_CODE='ABCDE' THEN G.EMAIL_ADDRESS END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.EMAIL_ADDRESS) AS email2
FROM   EMPLOYEE E
       INNER JOIN GENERAL_EMAIL G ON (G.ID=E.ID)
GROUP BY E.ID
ORDER BY E.ID;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | EMAIL1 | EMAIL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abbot@example.com,alice@example.com | alice_abbot@example.com |
| 2 | baron@example.com,beryl@example.com | beryl_baron@example.com |
| 3 | carol@example.com,count@example.com | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/60d0Hh-r)

Comment: Thank you so much MT0, I am learning so much :)
Thank you